# TableViewCell pass data to ViewController (Parse.com)?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller

Tell me what can be a mistake. I have 6 columns, two columns belong to TableViewCell. The other 4 belong to the ViewController. **How do I tie the rows correctly so that the match information matches its row in TableViewCell**.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailTennisViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageTennis: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var outClose: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTennis: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textTennis: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progTennis: UILabel!

    @IBAction func closeOut(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    var tenises : Tennis?

    func configureButton() {
        outClose.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * outClose.bounds.size.width
        outClose.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadTennis()
        configureButton()
    }


    func loadTennis () {
         let qwery = PFQuery(className: "tennis")
            qwery.getFirstObjectInBackground() { (object,error) ->Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.textTennis.text = object!["textTen"] as? String
                self.progTennis.text = object!["progTen"] as? String
                self.titleTennis.text = object!["titleTen"] as? String
                let imageFile = object!["tenImage"] as? PFFile
                imageFile?.getDataInBackground() { (data:Data?, error:Error?)->Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageData = data {
                              self.imageTennis.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
         }

     }
}
```

How to make the data string Parse.com How to make the data TableViewCell cells corresponded to the description ViewController. In my code, when the cell is opened, the same data is displayed. I uploaded 4 events and information about them. So the information about them opens up the same. How to make the one that is indicated by their "objectId"

Comment: explain more ...show images, code. unable to get your question

Comment: Here is my code. If you are good at understanding and will be able to help, but do not understand. I will be able to drop the screen. I can send you an email. I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: Are you trying to show Data to your `ViewController`, when someone click a cell from your `TableView` ? if that is not it, try to tell us your goal in this scenario, because it is a bit unclear of what you are trying to do

Comment: Yes, I have a segment, divided into 3 types. This is football, basketball, tennis. I have the name of the match and the picture. Then when I click on the match. For example, a football match between Italy and France, I get other data about another football match. That is, the lines ObjectId are not connected.